# How to arrange my GUI in java

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Hello I'm trying to make a gui for my java program but I'm stuck. I have made my buttonPanel but I don't know how to do next.

- I also want that when I click the ADD button to open a new window.
- And I don't know how to add on the right side of my buttons
  another panel in which I could list my students.
- And last thing under the panel that lists the stundents I would like to have some options to sort them ( like those with grades bigger than 5 etc).

I have managed to make my buttonPanel but I don't know how to continue. Please help me.

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MySwingTry extends JFrame {
    JPanel buttonPanel;


    public MySwingTry() {
        buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,0,5,0));
        JButton addButton = new JButton("Add student");
        JButton deleteButton = new JButton("Delete student");
        JButton printAllButton = new JButton("Print all");
        JButton printNrOfStudentsButton = new JButton("Print nr.");
        JButton writeButton = new JButton("Write File");
        JButton readButton = new JButton ("Read File");
        JButton serializeButton = new JButton("Serialize File");
        JButton deserializeButton = new JButton("DeserializeButton");
        BoxLayout boxLayout1 = new BoxLayout (buttonPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        buttonPanel.setLayout(boxLayout1);
        buttonPanel.add(addButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deleteButton);
        buttonPanel.add(printAllButton);
        buttonPanel.add(printNrOfStudentsButton);
        buttonPanel.add(writeButton);
        buttonPanel.add(readButton);
        buttonPanel.add(serializeButton);
        buttonPanel.add(deserializeButton);
        this.add(buttonPanel);

    }

//  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
//      if (event.getSource() == myButton) 
//          myLabel.setText("My button clicked");
//  }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MySwingTry first = new MySwingTry();
        first.setTitle("First try");
        first.setSize(300,500);
        first.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        first.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, one question at a time. You should ask one specific question, and in fact you yourself should try to solve each problem on your own, one at a time, each in isolation of the other.

Answer (score 4):

To answer the first part of your question:

> First I want all my buttons to be the same size, and there to be a little space between them.

Add your JButtons to a JPanel that uses a GridLayout with 4 parameters. The first 2 parameters will be row and column count, and the next two will be horizontal and vertical gap.

e.g.,

```
JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

// below: create a grid layout with 1 row, variable number of columns
// with a 5 points horizontal gap between each component and no vertical gap
buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 5, 0));
buttonPanel.add(button1);
buttonPanel.add(button2);
buttonPanel.add(button3);
//... etc

// now add the buttonPanel to the main GUI
```

---

As I have stated in my comment, you appear to be trying to solve too much all at once, and instead should concentrate on trying to solve ***one*** small problem at a time, in isolation of the others. First work on spacing your buttons, then try to tackle the next step. At each step if stuck, feel free to come here, but show us your attempt to solve that one step and ask your specific question regarding your misunderstandings and that one step.

Comment: I have solved the problem with the distance between the buttons but know the only thing that appears are my buttons : buttonPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,0,5,0));  How could I add something else?

Comment: @user3043278: It all depends on what you are adding your button panel to, and what layout it uses. If you're adding it to the JFrame (its contentPane really), understand that it uses a BorderLayout, and so you'll want to read the BorderLayout tutorial to see how it works.

Comment: how can I add a panel that would list all my students? How is it called?

Comment: @user3043278: Are you talking about a JList or JTable perhaps? I'm not sure as your question is a bit vague.

Comment: I want to have on the right side of my buttons a panel(I don't know how it's called ) where I should list the names of my students

Comment: @user3043278: then use a JList. The [tag:swing] info section will have a link to the Swing tutorials where you'll want to read up on using JLists. If you want to sort the Students though, a JTable may be better for this.

Comment: I have another question. My students all have an id, a name, a grade (these are standard id) but I also can have Graduate Students that have in addition a thesis name, grade and a supervisor name. How could I print the out, wouldn't it be a string too long to be printed?

Comment: @user3043278: You include what you want to include, no more no less. If you're using a JList, the two ways of doing this are via the class's `toString()` method or by using a custom list cell renderer.